# popViewControllerAnimated: doesn't release view controller from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have two view and second view is pushed from first view. For testing, I go to second view from first view and then I go back to first view. After that, I send nsnotification and in my second view, it receive my notification.

1) May I know why I receive notification in second view after it is pop up? For IBOutlets, I declare weak property also.

2) If it is still in memory, for other data like nsdictionary, nsstring, shall I use strong or weak property? Will those also  in memory?

3) If I don't want my second view in memory totally, how shall I do?

Comment: Show relevant code in your question. Have you confirmed whether the 2nd view controller's `dealloc` method is called or not? Do you unregister for the notification?

Comment: I have used this in my second VC though. https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl. I am not quite sure it will retain my view.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your second view controller is not released when you "go back" to the first view, then either

- You are not really "going back" - you are accidentally creating a new first view controller and pushing it, which is unlikely; or:
- You have a retain cycle in your second view controller.

I'm betting that you *do* have a retain cycle. You should try to track this down. You mention notifications: it is very easy to create an accidental extra retain when setting up a view controller as a notification observer, so that's probably the cause.

In particular, see [my book's discussion](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations) of this topic:

- If you called `addObserverForName:object:​queue:usingBlock:`, you will leak (under ARC) unless take elaborate precautions (such as doing the weak-strong dance in the block, to avoid a strongly retained `self`).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `addObserver:selector:name:object:` does not retain the observer. I use that many times and call it from `dealloc` just fine. In cases where I have forgotten to remove the observer, the `dealloc` is still called and the app crashes if the notification is sent and the deallocated view controller is still sent the notification.

Comment: Right you are, sorry @rmaddy - I was moving too fast as usual

Comment: Thanks you guys. I will check those.